# Different Result in Python for same Count

Tags: python-3.x, compare, sample

I have written a simple calculation, but get a different value than the sample. How does it happen that Python obviously rounds different?

```
PriceListOld = 23 
PriceListNew = []

if PriceListOld <=20:
    PriceListNew = PriceListOld * 0.8
elif PriceListOld >20 and PriceListOld <=50:
    PriceListNew = PriceListOld * 0.6
elif PriceListOld >50:
    PriceListNew = PriceListOld * 0.4
print(PriceListNew)     

print(23 -(4*2.3))    #<-- This is the Sample.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your demo code is unnecessarily complicated; you could as well have written:

```
>>> print(23-4*2.3)    #<-- This is the Sample.
13.8
>>> print(23*0.6)
13.799999999999999
```

> How does it happen that Python obviously rounds different?

It happens due to 0.6 not representable exactly in binary. If you just want a result of 13.8, you can get away with

```
>>> print(23*6/10)
13.8
```